# Do second-order theories always have irredundant axiomatizations?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, higher-order-logics

It's a [standard exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289290/28111) to show that every *countable* first-order theory has an irredundant axiomatization. For *uncountable* first-order theories, the result is much more difficult and was [proved by Reznikoff](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5171). For $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$, I believe the state-of-the-art for the analogous question is due to [Hjorth/Souldatos](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3422) following [X. Caicedo](https://math.uniandes.edu.co/archivos/publicaciones/IndependentsetsofaxiomsinL-kappa,alpha.pdf),  *Independent sets of axioms in $L_{\kappa,\alpha}$*, Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 22 (1981), 219–223.

I don't recall seeing anything, however, about *second-order* logic:

> Suppose $T$ is a second-order theory - of arbitrary cardinality, in an arbitrary language. Must there be a second-order theory $S$ in the same language such that $(i)$ $S$ and $T$ are semantically equivalent (= have the same classes of models) but $(ii)$ no proper subset of $S$ is semantically equivalent to $S$?

Again the countable case is easy, but the uncountable case is unclear to me (at a glance I don't think Reznikoff's argument generalizes). More generally, I'd be interested in any sources treating the "irredundance property" in a broader class of logics than just the $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa\lambda}$s.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb, but I'm having trouble figuring out how you even want to formalize this question.  I mean, can't you easily give second order theories which lack any set models?  Ok, we can work in NBG but can you reassure me that I'm being dumb to worry that when we do this it isn't going to do violence to our intuitive notion of semantically equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a proof of Reznikoff’s theorem I found among my notes, not quite following Reznikoff’s proof. I stared at it for a while, and it seems to apply to second-order logic just the same; in fact, the only property of first-order logic it uses is that any sentence contains only finitely many non-logical symbols, and there are only countably many sentences in any given finite language. Let me know if I missed something.

We say that a theory $T$ in a language $L$ *depends* on a predicate or function symbol $s\in L$ if there are models $A\models T$, $B\let\nmodels\nvDash\nmodels T$ such that $A\let\res\restriction\res(L\let\bez\smallsetminus\bez\{s\})=B\res(L\bez\{s\})$. Let $L_T$ denote the set of symbols $s\in L$ on which $T$ depends. If $L'\subseteq L$, let $T\res L'$ be the set of $L'$-sentences valid in $T$.

> **Lemma 1:** If $A\models T$ and $A\res L_T=B\res L_T$, then $B\models T$.

**Proof:** Fix $\phi\in T$, we will show $B\models\phi$. Let $\{s_i:i<n\}$ enumerate the symbols of $L\bez L_T$ occurring in $\phi$, and for $i\le n$, let $A_i$ denote $A$ with the interpretation of $s_j$ changed to $s_j^B$ for each $j<i$. Applying $n$ times the definition of $L_T$, we see that $A_i\models T$ for each $i\le n$, thus $A_n\models\phi$. But $A_n$ and $B$ agree on all symbols that occur in $\phi$, hence $B\models\phi$. **QED**

> **Lemma 2:** $T\res L_T$ is equivalent to $T$.

**Proof:**
For every $L$-sentence $\phi$, we define an $L_T$-sentence $\phi'$ by replacing all predicates $P\in L\bez L_T$ with $\bot$, and all functions $F\in L\bez L_T$ by a fixed fresh variable $x$, and putting a universal quantifier $\forall x$ in front of the whole formula. Similarly, if $A$ is an $L_T$-model and $c\in A$, we define an $L$-model $A_c$ expanding $A$ by $P^{A_c}=\varnothing$ and $F^{A_c}(\vec a)=c$. Clearly,
$$A\models\phi'\iff\forall c\in A\:A_c\models\phi.$$
If $T\models\phi$ and $A\models T$, then $(A\res L_T)_c\models T$ for each $c\in A$ by Lemma 1, hence $(A\res L_T)_c\models\phi$, and $A\models\phi'$. That is, if $T\models\phi$, then $\phi'\in T\res L_T$.

Consequently, if $A\res L_T\models T\res L_T$, then $A\res L_T\models\{\phi':T\models\phi\}$, i.e., $(A\res L_T)_c\models T$ for any $c\in A$, and therefore $A\models T$ by Lemma 1. Thus, every model of $T\res L_T$ is a model of $T$. **QED**

**NB:** Alternatively, Lemma 2 can be proved using the Craig interpolation lemma.

> **Lemma 3:** If $T$ depends on $\kappa\ge\omega$ symbols, there exist models $\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ and sentences $\{\phi_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ valid in $T$ such that
>
> $$A_\alpha\models\phi_\beta\iff\alpha\ne\beta\tag1$$
>
> for all $\alpha,\beta<\kappa$, and
>
> $$T\models\phi\implies\{\alpha<\kappa:A_\alpha\nmodels\phi\}\text{ is finite}\tag2$$
> for all sentences $\phi$.

**Proof:**
Assume that $T$ depends on all symbols in $\{s_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$, and pick models $A_\alpha\nmodels T$, $A'_\alpha\models T$ such that $A_\alpha$ and $A'_\alpha$ differ only in the interpretation of $s_\alpha$. For each $\alpha<\kappa$, fix a sentence $\xi_\alpha$ such that $T\models\xi_\alpha$ and $A_\alpha\nmodels\xi_\alpha$.

Since $A'_\alpha\models T$, we see that $A_\alpha\nmodels\phi$ for $T\models\phi$ can only happen when $s_\alpha$ appears in $\phi$. Since only finitely many symbols appear in $\phi$, this implies (2). Moreover, considering $\phi=\xi_\alpha$, it implies that for each $\alpha<\kappa$, only finitely many $A_\beta$ can satisfy the same sentences as $A_\alpha$, thus there are $\kappa$ inequivalent models on the list; w.l.o.g., we may assume that $A_\alpha\not\equiv A_\beta$ whenever $\beta\ne\alpha$.

Fix $\alpha<\kappa$. We already know that $\{\beta\ne\alpha:A_\beta\nmodels\xi_\alpha\}$ is finite; let us enumerate it as $\{\beta_{\alpha,i}:i<n_\alpha\}$. For each $i<n_\alpha$, we fix a sentence $\zeta_{\alpha,i}$ such that $A_{\beta_{\alpha,i}}\models\zeta_{\alpha,i}$ and $A_\alpha\nmodels\zeta_{\alpha,i}$. Then we put

$$\phi_\alpha=\xi_\alpha\lor\bigvee_{i<n_\alpha}\zeta_{\alpha,i},$$

and observe that it makes (1) hold. **QED**

> **Theorem:** Every theory $T$ has an independent axiomatization.

**Proof:**
Put $\kappa=|L_T|$, and assume first that $\kappa$ is infinite. Let $\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ and $\{\phi_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ be as in Lemma 3. Enumerate $T\res L_T$ as $\{\chi_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$, and define

$$\begin{align*}
\psi_\alpha&=\Bigl(\let\ET\bigwedge\ET_{\beta\colon A_\beta\nmodels\chi_\alpha}\phi_\beta\Bigr)\to\chi_\alpha,\\
S&=\{\phi_\alpha\land\psi_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}.
\end{align*}$$
Since $T\equiv T\res L_T$ by Lemma 2, it is clear that $S\equiv T$. Moreover, $A_\alpha\models\phi_\beta\land\psi_\beta$ for $\beta\ne\alpha$, but $A_\alpha\nmodels\phi_\alpha$, hence $S$ is independent.

If $\kappa$ is finite, $T$ has a countable axiomatization $\{\phi_n:n<\omega\}$ by Lemma 2. Put

$$\begin{align*}
\psi_n&=\Bigl(\ET_{i<n}\phi_i\Bigr)\to\phi_n,\\
S&=\{\psi_n:n\in\omega,\text{ $\psi_n$ is not logically valid}\}.
\end{align*}$$

Since $\ET_{i\le n}\psi_i$ is equivalent to $\ET_{i\le n}\phi_n$, $S\equiv T$. Moreover, since $\psi_n\in S$ is not valid, there is $A_n\models\neg\psi_n$. This means $A_n\models\phi_i$ for $i<n$ and $A_n\models\neg\phi_n$, which implies $A_n\models\{\psi_i:i\ne n\}$. Thus, $S$ is independent. **QED**

Comment: This is nice, and I think it works! A quick question: you say Craig isn't available in SOL, but isn't it trivialy true in SOL since we can directly quantify over the "extra symbols" in the interpolant?

Comment: Ah, ok, you are right. I didn’t really think about it, and assumed there was a problem with it, as this is the only sophisticated property of first-order logic used in Reznikoff’s proof. So why doesn’t Reznikoff’s proof apply to second-order logic?

Comment: Doesn't Reznikoff use compactness? (Or did I have a fascinating logic hallucination, as one sometimes does?) BTW I can't award the bounty for another 3 hours, but as soon as I can I will. Thanks as always!

Comment: I see. I didn’t really study the proof in detail.

Comment: As a very-belated comment, I think that your argument also shows independent axiomatizability for second-order logic in higher-order languages; since interpolation fails in that setting, Reznikoff's original argument doesn't trivially go through.